# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'update')

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, fastify

```
function markAsLoggedOut(user: UserInstance) {
  return user.update({ token: null });
}
```

I got this error in this place of code.How can I resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide us more information, and if possible a working code snippet so we can try to reproduce your problem. Also have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
All of this said, your problem is that your user here is null. So you should check your code to keep track of the value of ```user``` and see where it has null as a value.

Comment: If `user` is `null` then it won't have an `update` method. You need to either ensure that `null` isn't passed into the function (there isn't enough context to tell how) or test to see if `user` is `null` and … so something else (no idea what you might want to do in that case).

Answer (score 0):

There may be an issue with your type `UserInstance` if it doesn't contain `null` or `undefined`

But it is possible to account for either by changing the type your function expects:

```js
function markAsLoggedOut(user: UserInstance | null) {
  // Do something
}
```

Or by changing the underlying type:

```
type UserInstance = {} | null
```

However you do it, you then need to check if `user` (`UserInstance`) has a value first.
You could do this with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or an `if` statement:

#### optional chaining

```js
function markAsLoggedOut(user: UserInstance | null) {
  return user?.update({ token: null });
}
```

#### `if` statement

```js
function markAsLoggedOut(user: UserInstance | null) {
  if (user) {
    return user.update({ token: null });
  }
}
```